# css formatting string content

Tags: css, html

I have a string with the value as :

`1 - If (a12 + aaGrossVehicleWeight is equal to 100 + 60) test1 = aaModelCode(Always Overwrite) test1 = 42 a12 = aumtReadingDate+1 
2 - If (a12 is equal to 20) test1 = (Always Overwrite) test1 = a12 = 1+2`

Is it possible using CSS to format the above content with different font and color as shown in the attached screenshot?

[different font color for the content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b9sw.png)

[image]

Comment: attached a class to it and apply css

Comment: I am new to css. can u give me a sample code that will be great..

Answer (score 0):

Something like this hypothetically,

```
<ul>
    <li>1 - If (a12 + aaGrossVehicleWeight is equal to 100 + 60) test1 = aaModelCode(Always Overwrite) test1 = 42 a12 = aumtReadingDate+1</li>
    <li class="style2">2 - If (a12 is equal to 20) test1 = (Always Overwrite) test1 = a12 = 1+2</li>
</ul>

<style>
    .style2{
        font-size: 18px;
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Giri, thanks for the reply. But these values are getting it dynamically from database and assign it to the div element "  <div id="TriggerdetailsDiv" style="display:none;width:400px">
        <textarea id="triggerdetailsid" name="triggerdetailsid" class="textarea" cols="50" rows="10"readonly="readonly"></textarea>
   </div> " so using the class "textarea" i can only format the entire content and not part by part. Say for example if i want to highlight the value "If" in one color and the condition in another color and the value  in different color how to achieve it with the same class and css?

Comment: Does that have to be a textarea element? Can;t pull the data into a other elements?

Comment: not necessarily it has to be in textarea.. we can put it into any element and display the data with different font/color..

Comment: If you are looping through data, try to insert them into separate divs or spans and then you could use :nth-child() psuedo to target the specific part

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML definition list , concept of classes and use classes to apply color for each part of the text. Sample code is shown below.

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
.darkblue {
  color: darkBlue;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt class="blue">1.Some random text</dt>
  <dd class="red">dummy text dummy text<span class="darkblue"> dummy text</span></dd>
  <dt class="blue">2.Some random text</dt>
  <dd class="red">dummy text dummy text dummy text<span class="darkblue"> dummy text</span></dd>
  <dt class="blue">3.Some random text</dt>
  <dd class="red">dummy text dummy text dummy text<span class="darkblue"> dummy text</span></dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: For static text, yes we can able to make use of your suggestions. But in my case, data is dynamic and come as a single string value. Need help in splitting the data and formatting with different font/color is the question.

Comment: You can use javascript substring function - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Comment: How are you adding the text to dom ?

Comment: using ajax, i am fetching value from the database and assigning it to the div element (initially, I am assigning the entire string in textarea). now I need to format it with different font/color